# Unsupported configuration: ... armeabi-v7a-emu.so in Mono for Android v4.0

Tags: xamarin.android

I have just downloaded the latest Mono for Android (v4.0) and am trying to load a test app into a level 14 API emulator.  In both Visual Studio 10 and Monodevelop, I am getting the same problem when packaging the app.  Here's what I get in VS.

```
monodroid : error 1: System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported configuration: Could not load resource 'libmono-android.shared.armeabi-v7a-emu.so'
```

I **have** installed the "ARM EABI v7a System Image" using the Android SDK manager.  I can see the system.img file in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\system-images\android-14\armeabi-v7a.

I created an emulator using level 14 API, and this starts up and runs without problem.  I modified the project properties to target Android 4.0 and the armeabi-v7a architecture.  The app is simply the unmodified test app created automatically when you select the android application template.  I am running Vista.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks,   Stuart F.

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation version does not allow you to build the armeabi-v7a version, because there was never a armeabi-v7a emulator until now, and the evaluation version only allows you to deploy to emulators.

Use the armeabi version, which should work fine on the armeabi-v7a emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I suspected it had to be something like this.  I had tried this before, but didn't manage to get it to work, as the running armeabi-v7a emulator did not appear in the "select device" list.  I have now set this emulator as the default device in the VS  Android options - that bypasses the select device dialogue and now the app loads and runs.  Thanks again!   Stuart F.